# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel on Android. Will it work?

Tags: c#, android, excel, office-interop

I am trying out different apis to programmatically create excel documents. My main concern is that the api is as cheap as posible, easy to use and can be used in a comercial project without any restrictions. So I came across Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. As I understand an MS office installed is a must so that this api will work.

I gues my question is: Is it possible to make Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel also work on android devices?

PS: Ugly but true: I may not disclose my sourcecode, so GPLv3 is out of the question, looking for sth with MIT license or similar.

10xs

Comment: You could use DocumentFormat.OpenXml. It is both free and standalone. Link: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml. I use it in combination with Open XML SDK to create Word and Excel files.

Comment: Forgot to say it ships with an [MIT license](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/blob/master/LICENSE).

Comment: The "interop" works only with Desktop Office installations, both Windows and Mac. For other devices you can create an add-in using Office JS APIs or the Open XML SDK. Both cost nothing and require no license to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't count on Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel working successfully on Android devices. There are probably better tools for achieving what you want.

See https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml and my comment.

Comment: Yes, and it  is MIT licensed. I am working with it now,  it is very verbouse, almost java-like (no shortcuts), but free of charge and thats why it will have to do. 10xs